# Does deleting sed pattern space with 'd' erase hold space as well?

Tags: sed

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

This is expected:

```
$ echo -e "foo\nbar" | sed -n 'h; x; p'
foo
bar
```

I put every line in the hold space, then swap hold space and pattern space, then print the pattern space, so every line is printed. Now, why is the following different?

```
$ echo -e "foo\nbar" | sed -n 'h; d; x; p'
```

I thought that wouldn't be, because I delete the pattern space before swapping, so the stored line should be put back to the pattern space anyway. It's the *hold space* that should be empty after `x;`, right? I delete the pattern space, **then** swap. Where does the line I've saved go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess it's related to the following line in `man sed`:

> d      Delete pattern space.  Start next cycle.

The following works as expected:

```
$ echo -e "foo\nbar" | sed -n 'h; s/.*//; g; p'
foo
bar
```

Sorry for bothering you guys.

Answer (score 7):

When you use `d`, the pattern space is cleared, the next line is read, and processing starts over from the beginning of the script. Thus, you never actually reach the `x` and `p` steps, instead just copying to the hold space and deleting.